# PyMC3 do not converge

Tags: machine-learning, python, mcmc, probabilistic-programming

I'm trying to run a simple logistic regression on PyMC3. Here the code:

```
with pm.Model() as logistic_model:
    alpha=pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=100)
    beta1=pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=100)
    beta2=pm.Normal('beta2', mu=0, sd=100)

    argtemp=alpha + beta1*data['age'].values +beta2*data['educ'].values
    prob=pm.invlogit(argtemp)
    Y_obs = pm.Bernoulli('Y_obs', p=prob, observed=data['income_more_50K'].values)
    map_estimate = pm.find_MAP()
    sampler=pm.Metropolis()

    trace= pm.sample(40000, step=sampler, start=map_estimate)
```

The sampler run, but at the end it gives this error:

```
The gelman-rubin statistic is larger than 1.4 for some parameters. The sampler did not converge.
The estimated number of effective samples is smaller than 200 for some parameters.
```

Can someone help me in understanding what is wrong, and why the sampler do not converge?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the MAP estimation. Commenting out that line makes the code works.

Details in  [this thread](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/metropolis-sampler-do-not-sample-traceplot-gives-flat-plots/1362/6) in the PyMC Discourse forum.